# Boost::spirit processes rule with branches incorrectly

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-variant

I wrote the code listed below. The compiler reports me an error: 'none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types'.

I use MSVC 11.0 and Boost 1.51.0. Each branch of expression for `m_oQueryIterationExpression` works correctly but together they do not. Any clues?

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>

namespace Ns
{
    struct Regexp     { std::string m_strEntity; };
    struct String     { std::string m_strEntity; };
    struct Identifier { std::string m_strEntity; };

    typedef int Number;

    typedef std::string Operation;
    typedef boost::variant<Regexp, Number, String, Identifier> Operand;
    typedef boost::tuple<Operation, boost::optional<std::vector<Operand> > > OperationWithOperands;

    struct QueryConcatenation;

    typedef boost::tuple<boost::recursive_wrapper<QueryConcatenation>, boost::optional<char> > typeA;
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<OperationWithOperands> > typeB;

    typedef boost::variant<typeA, typeB> QueryIteration;

    struct QueryConcatenation {
        typedef std::vector<QueryIteration> TEntity;
        TEntity m_oEntity;
    };
}

int main()
{
    using namespace Ns;
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    qi::rule<char*, QueryConcatenation()>                                m_oQueryConcatenationExpression;
    qi::rule<char*, QueryIteration()>                                    m_oQueryIterationExpression;
    qi::rule<char*, std::vector<std::vector<OperationWithOperands> >() > m_oQueryNode;

    m_oQueryIterationExpression %= 
        qi::attr_cast<typeA, typeA>( '(' >> m_oQueryConcatenationExpression >> ')' >> -(qi::char_("*+?")) )
        | m_oQueryNode;
}
```

Comment: I edited the post to make it less verbose. Actually **[this is what](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3412f26558a949a2a470a291bdbbaaae)** a real [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions/22762#22762) _would_ have looked like (24 lines)

Comment: Also note how your declaration of `m_oQueryNode` lacks the parentheses with `qi::rule<It, attr_type` **`()`** `, ...>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the thing is, your assignment **is** ambiguous, and the compiler is just letting you know. See what happens:

```
typedef boost::tuple<
            boost::recursive_wrapper<STreeConstructionRuleQueryConcatenation>, 
            boost::optional<char>
        > typeA;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<STreeConstructionRuleOperationWithOperands> > typeB;

typedef boost::variant<typeA, typeB> typeAB;
typedef typeAB STreeConstructionRuleQueryIteration;
```

Now let's see about attribute compatibility in some rules:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, typeA(),  ascii::space_type> ruleA;
qi::rule<Iterator, typeB(),  ascii::space_type> ruleB;
qi::rule<Iterator, typeAB(), ascii::space_type> ruleAB;

// these are intended to compile, and they do:
ruleA  %= ( '(' >> m_oQueryConcatenationExpression >> ')' >> -(qi::char_("*+?")) );
ruleB  %= m_oQueryNode;
// so far, so good

// ---- Now, ideally we like the assignments to be mutually exclusive:

// This fails to assign, good! :
// ruleB  %= ( '(' >> m_oQueryConcatenationExpression >> ')' >> -(qi::char_("*+?")) );

// But HERE is the surprise:
ruleA  %= m_oQueryNode; // uhoh m_oQueryNode can be assigned to a typeA attribute as well
```

This is what is making the initialization of the variant ambiguous on the second branch of the parser expression: it could be either!

Fortunately, there is a very simple solution: just make the type explicit:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, typeAB(), ascii::space_type> ruleAB;
ruleAB %= ruleA | ruleB;
```

You see, by making subrules expose the *explicit* type-member of the variant, you remove all doubt (an exact match is fine to the compiler). The same effect could be reached doing:

```
ruleAB %= qi::attr_cast_type<typeA, typeA>( '(' >> m_oQueryConcatenationExpression >> ')' >> -(qi::char_("*+?")) ) | ruleB;
```

This removes the need for another subrule, but at the cost of legibility, IMO.

Here is your full original code, fixed with a subrule: http://liveworkspace.org/code/5a7a8046b713beefba211a6a54219368 (change the naming...)